# jQuery: find index of td containing "Up", then use that index to select same td in next tr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>up</td><td>d</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>99</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

but it can also look like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>up</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
<tr><td>99</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

How do I do if I would like to select the td in the row below the text "up"?
This code gets the index of "up":

```
$('table tr:eq(0) td:contains("up")').index();
```

And this is what I want to work:

```
$('table tr:eq(1) td:eq($('table tr:eq(0) td:contains("up")').index())');
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `+` operator for string concatenation:

```
$('table tr:eq(1) td:eq(' + $('table tr:eq(0) td:contains("up")').index() + ')');
```

To make the code more understandable, I'd write it as:

```
var upindex = $('table tr:eq(0) td:contains("up")').index();
$('table tr:eq(1) td:eq(' + upindex + ')').whatever();
```

Comment: I tend to believe you, but manual says, returns `number`? http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: What's the problem with that? Javascript converts numbers to strings when concatenating.

Comment: Sorry, was on the wrong path, of course you had to use string concatenation, if you want to kept up *that* concept. Was to look for more like the others did and was sloooow. ;) I usually try to be close to the OP's question ( in my one or two answers compared to you;) ), but this time I searched different and did not understand your solution, haha!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
var $tr = $('table tr'),
    i   = $tr.first().find('td:contains(up)').index();

var $cell = $tr.eq(1).find('td').eq(i);
```

You can also use the `children` property and filter the target element:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table'),
    tr = table.children[0].children;
    td = tr[0].children, 
    l = td.length,
    ind = null;    

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (td[i].innerHTML.indexOf('up') > -1) {
       ind = i;
       break;
    }
}
var cell = tr[1].children[ind];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var idx=$('td:contains("up")');
console.log(idx.closest('tr').next().find('td').eq(idx.index()).text())
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p2SVT/)**